# How to get only the road names on a route, with google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding

For a project im doing, I need to get the road names on a route.

So when i go from Amsterdam to Eindhoven, i pass for example the following roads, A4, A5, A27

My question is, how can i get these roads from the google maps api by giving my departure and destination?

All help is very appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Where are you using the Google Maps API you get a JSON format return.

like this;

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "results": [ {
    "types": street_address,
    "formatted_address": "275-291 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA",
    "address_components": [ {
      "long_name": "275-291",
      "short_name": "275-291",
      "types": street_number
    }, {
      "long_name": "Bedford Ave",
      "short_name": "Bedford Ave",
      "types": route
    }, {
      "long_name": "New York",
      "short_name": "New York",
      "types": [ "locality", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Brooklyn",
      "short_name": "Brooklyn",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_3", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "Kings",
      "short_name": "Kings",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "New York",
      "short_name": "NY",
      "types": [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "United States",
      "short_name": "US",
      "types": [ "country", "political" ]
    }, {
      "long_name": "11211",
      "short_name": "11211",
      "types": postal_code
    } ],
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 40.7142298,
        "lng": -73.9614669
      },
      "location_type": "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
      "viewport": {
        "southwest": {
          "lat": 40.7110822,
          "lng": -73.9646145
        },
        "northeast": {
          "lat": 40.7173774,
          "lng": -73.9583193
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Pick the long_name, and short_name from address.

Comment: Hi ivanfromer,

Thanks for your response, but this is not what i mean. 

I need the road names for a specific route. Let say you go from manhattan to wall street NY, i want to have the roads your passing when going from manhattan to Wall street.

I hope you understand what i Mean.

Help is really appreciated.

Comment: this URL should be help you: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/?hl=en